# Multiple Reports (*.rdlc) Showing in One Report Viewer Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

We have 3 reports for parts: Approved, Cancelled and OnHold.  They are independent reports that display different data for each report.  The user would like to go to a "Report", where it lists each report inside a Report Viewer control and they can see all three reports (I would assume Page One shows, then page break.  Page Two is the next report, Page Three is the last report when the user clicks "next" button inside the report viewer).

How would one go about accomplishing this?  Each report has its own header and details, so I created each as its own .rdlc, but can't seem to figure out how to display them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Make a 4th report and add each of the other three as a subreport of the new one.

Comment: But they are not subreports and each has a different header and footer.  Is this possible with a subreport?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've worked with reports, but I remember doing something similar a few years ago.  Give it a try.